# Richfaces ExtendedDataTable

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, richfaces

Is it possible to achieve grouped headers in RichFaces ExtendedDataTable, as it does not support rowbreakbefore.

I have tried the following

```
<rich:extendedDataTable id="pivotTable" rowIndexVar="rowIndex">
        <c:forEach items="#{richPivotBean.headerRows}" var="columnObject">
            <rich:column breakrowbefore="#{columnobject.startone}"
                colspan="#{columnobject.colspan}" rowspan="#{columnobject.rowspan}">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="#{columnobject.colheadertext}" />
                </f:facet>
            </rich:column>
        </c:forEach>
    </rich:extendedDataTable>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the answer is a simple "no", you need to use rich:dataTable to get this functionality. Why are you using extendedDataTable rather than dataTable, normally this would be for scrolling or row selection but I see no evidence of this in your code.

Comment: Ok, this has come up numerous times on the richfaces forum and I've not seen anyone come up with a good solution yet but there's nothing to stop you searching through yourself. Ultimately though there's nothing you can't do client side with jQuery/javascript.